# Google Developer console trying to build android project with maven-android-plugin

Tags: android, maven, google-compute-engine

I'm new to the whole Google Developer console thing. Right now I can get the server to sync with Git and fetch a copy when ever there's a push to it. However, I'm trying to build and test the program with Maven-Android-Plugin and no matter what I've tried, i'll always get this error:

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1.1 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

With the compute engine that I've got, I've installed mavven 3.1.1 and have also installed java sdk 1.7. I have used the console command $JAVA_HOME and mvn-v and both are showing the right versions.

Is there something else I need to setup to get it to work correctly?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
The compute-engine that I've selected is Maven Junit test.

Comment: Does that pom work elsewhere, i.e. is this problem specific to this environment, or a general problem with the dependencies?

Comment: The pom is working locally on a windows server. This is the first time I'm going through a full pipeline on a linux server and so I thought I might have missed something with the setup on the Linux server. However, searching through Google, I can't seem to find any similar cases